# Animating Tile with Blitting taking up Memory

Tags: actionscript-3, memory-efficiency, bit-blit

I am trying to animate a specific tile in my 2d Array, using blitting. The animation consists of three different 16x16 sprites in a tilesheet. Now that works perfect with the code below. BUT it's causing memory leakage. Every second the FlashPlayer is taking up +140 kb more in memory. **What part of the following code could possibly cause the leak:**

```
//The variable Rectangle finds where on the 2d array we should clear the pixels
//Fillrect follows up by setting alpha 0 at that spot before we copy in nxt Sprite
//Tiletype is a variable that holds what kind of tile the next tile in animation is
//(from tileSheet)
//drawTile() gets Sprite from tilesheet and copyPixels it into right position on canvas

        public function animateSprite():void{

                    tileGround.bitmapData.lock();

                    if(anmArray[0].tileType > 42){
                        anmArray[0].tileType = 40;
                        frameCount = 0;
                    }
                    var rect:Rectangle = new Rectangle(anmArray[0].xtile * ts, anmArray[0].ytile * ts, ts, ts);
                    tileGround.bitmapData.fillRect(rect, 0);

                    anmArray[0].tileType = 40 + frameCount;
                    drawTile(anmArray[0].tileType, anmArray[0].xtile, anmArray[0].ytile);

                    frameCount++;

                    tileGround.bitmapData.unlock();
                }



        public function drawTile(spriteType:int, xt:int, yt:int):void{

                    var tileSprite:Bitmap = getImageFromSheet(spriteType, ts);
                    var rec:Rectangle = new Rectangle(0, 0, ts, ts);
                    var pt:Point = new Point(xt * ts, yt * ts);
                    tileGround.bitmapData.copyPixels(tileSprite.bitmapData, rec, pt, null, null, true);

                }


                public function getImageFromSheet(spriteType:int, size:int):Bitmap{

                    var sheetColumns:int = tSheet.width/ts;
                    var col:int = spriteType % sheetColumns;
                    var row:int = Math.floor(spriteType/sheetColumns);
                    var rec:Rectangle = new Rectangle(col * ts, row * ts, size, size);
                    var pt:Point = new Point(0,0);

                    var correctTile:Bitmap = new Bitmap(new BitmapData(size, size, false, 0));
                    correctTile.bitmapData.copyPixels(tSheet, rec, pt, null, null, true);
                    return correctTile;

                }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main memory consumption is because you're allocating new memory by creating a new Bitmap in your `getImageFromSheet` method.

You could write your code without any of these allocations. Instead of creating new Points and Rectanlges and Bitmaps every time, you could use two private member variables for the `Point` and `Rectangle` (where you simply change properties) and perform the `copyPixels` method directly from your sprite-sheet to your canvas. There's no need for the intermediate copy to a `Bitmap`. *If* you still want to pass around new bitmap-data, use `BitmapData` directly and not a `Bitmap` which is only a `DisplayObject` wrapper so that you can add it to the flash stage (which you don't need).

How long did you monitor your memory consumption? That allocated memory should actually be released by the garbage collector... but it would of course be better if you did not allocate that memory in the first place (since it's redundant).

Comment: @bummzack Nice! I changed all the Points and the Rectangles to private class variables and changed their properties within the functions (pt.x or rec.width, etc..). Worked perfectly! But I acctually need the Bitmap to contain the BitmapData, cause some images that I fetch from the tilesheet will be added to a Movieclip on the stage (addchild(bitmap)). I tried to do the same with the Bitmap varibales and BitmapData variables, changing them to private class variable, but when I then try to change  myBitmapdata.width property, it says it's "read-only". Is there any other way I could achieve this?

Comment: No, you can't change the width of a BitmapData. If you're adding these Bitmaps to the stage it's normal that your memory increases. The memory should free up whenever you remove these objects from the stage though. You could optimize this by using the same `BitmapData` in several `Bitmaps` though. That way every sprite "coordinate" would only require memory once.

Comment: @bummzack, That did help a lot, to use the same BitmapData in several Bitmaps, and removing them from renewing each time. They are now only renewed once and then recycled. Although there is one BitmapData that will change size depending on the current level (2d Array size), and sadly thats the one that will consume most memory. Gave me an idea though, what if I did all of this in reverse, let's say I kept the bitmaps in their place, and instead dispose() the bitmaps and removeChild the movieclips the movieclips BEFORE I add the MC's again and add new Bitmaps? Would that be efficient?

Comment: Not sure if I really understand. Another approach would be to use the [scrollRect](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObject.html#scrollRect) property the Bitmap to show only the desired area of the image. That way you would always use the same BitmapData (the full image) but only specify the portion to show.

Comment: @bummzack Funny enough, I am already using scrollRect. I tried your advice, I changed the BitmapData size (width/height) to a full image, 2000 * 2000 pixels, and then made it a class variable. Now the memory in the Task Manager shows 52,000 K as oppose to 16,000 K, which is bad. I think 16,000 K for a flash game is acceptable though. Based on all the suggestions you have given in this thread, about optimizing the Bitmap and BitmapData, has trimmed it down tremendously! Which is great. The memory used to show 50, 000+ K, but now using the same BitmapData instead of several, its down to 16,000.

Comment: @Kid I'm kinda confused now. Why does the `scrollRect` approach use more memory? It shouldn't use any additional memory at all, because you should only have *one single instance* of your BitmapData at all times. Have a look at this [example code](http://pastie.org/2127854). You might have another problem in your architecture if that approach still gives you memory leaks.

Comment: @bummzack It's not the scrollRect that causes more memory, its the fact that I create a new BitmapData() that is up to 2000 pixels long. Isn't that reasonable? The bigger the BitmapDatas you create the bigger memory gets consumed? I'll try to decipher your code, meanwhile, here is how mine is setup, to give you a better idea of the map building code: http://pastie.org/private/zyfnqem5yley8ktg5jt8la

Comment: @Kid: I'm not sure I can help you here.. whether you're going to allocate one bitmap with 2000x2000 pixels, or 100 tiles with 200x200 pixels each insn't going to matter, both approaches are going to use the same amount of memory. Looking at your code I still don't get why you have a `tileGround`, a `backGround` and some `correctTilebitmapdata`. Look at the code I provided. It uses a single sprite-sheet and uses `scrollRect` to display these tiles at multiple locations and animate them without additional memory cost..

Comment: @bummzack, My explanations hasn't been elaborate enough, my bad. Looking at your code, you aren't using a bitmapData canvas for your tiles, you are immediately adding them to stage, whilst I am blitting them onto a prepared canvas instead, namely tileGround. Basically I am using tileGround as a canvas for all the tiles to be copied onto. And backgGround as a canvas for a (parallax) background image to be copied onto. They are separated because the backGround and the tileGround will move independently when the player moves using the keyboard arrow keys.

Comment: Now the stage is only 650x400 pixels big,but the tileGround bitmapData could be up to 1920*1920 pixels big (depending on which level you are at). Using scrollRect on tileGround, I only display a portion of those maps, namely 650x400 portion (visible area of stage). So if player moves right,the tileGround canvas scrolls left, and keeps doing so until player reaches tileGrounds width. Now depending on how big the level is(the width and height of tileGround bitmapData), lets say I set it to 5000x5000,then obviously more memory would be used since it is now bigger than the previous map(1920x1920).

Comment: @bummzack Now that I see that you don't use anykind of canvas for your tiles though. Maybe I should just immediately add them onto a movieclip. Would that be a good optimization method? For some reason I thought blitting meant copying from a sprite sheet, onto a bitmap, repeatedly.

Comment: @Kid: Yes, blitting would mean to copy them to a BitmapData Object. I proposed the other approach, since you told me you have to add them to a MovieClip using "addChild"... that seems to be related to something else then? Anyway, why not simply create your background with a width of `stageWidth + maxTileWidth`? Then use [BitmapData.scroll](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/BitmapData.html#scroll%28%29) to scroll the bitmap and append new columns of tiles whenever necessary. Should be simple to implement and probably the most memory efficient way.

Comment: @bummzack You're right, I did say I am adding them to a movieclip. I'm combining blitting and movieclips. I am blitting the tiles to the tileGround bitmapData canvas, but then, I addChild that tileGround bitmapData to a movieclip on stage. So the WHOLE current level/tileGround is inside a movieclip called tileMc. THEN I scrollRect that movieclip. It was an easy solution, since all I had to do was control the movieclips properties to manipulate movement or any transitions to the level... and since I'm only a mediocre programmer, it was the best I could do.

Comment: I feel like I've confused you more than necessary, I wish I could show the alpha version of the game so far, it would clear some things up. But there is no private messaging here unfortunately, an I don't wanna make this file public just yet. The game mechanics are working perfectly, and having +-18, 000 K memory usage is pretty good for a flashgame, it's just that I like to optimize my game as much as I can muster.

Comment: Anyway, your idea about appending new columns (and rows, the game scrolls both ways) whenever the player moves into new areas is a good idea, this means I have to erase the tiles that scroll out of the stage and at the same time add new ones as the player is moving around. Wouldn't that add a lot of code? and isn't Scrollrect already doing this (deleting was not on screen)?

Comment: @Kid: `scrollRect` just defines the currently visible portion of a `DisplayObject`. If you use that to only show a portion of an image, the full image will still reside in memory at all times. `scroll` on the other hand is only available on `BitmapData` and actually shifts the image data by the given amount. Sure, adding/removing level data dynamically is going to be more complicated to code, but will be more (memory) efficient if your level spans across multiple screens. Depending on the level size this might be worth it or not. You decide.

Comment: @bummzack: Yah thanks man, I'm gonna finish the level editor and plan out all the levels. Thereafter I'll see what kind of efficiency modifications I will do to the scrolling part. Somehow removing and adding tiles seems like I'd be trading memory for a processor intensive treatment instead (since it's constantly checking tiles placements, with sometimes extensive for-loops and numerous functions). With BitmapData.scroll() you have to copypixel the tiles onto the canvas continually as you move, but it leaves out manually deleting columns of tiles while it seems to handle it on it's own.

Comment: This page is bookmarked :)

Comment: @Kid: You know how to accept answers, do you? Just click the checkmark below the up- and downvote buttons :)

Comment: @bummzack Holy..didn't know that, its done now though! I need to backtrack threads i've started...